# Unhandled exception: Bad state: Future already completed

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Running some very simple code but got this Unhandled exception which I have no idea what's going on since I'm quite new to this language.

The problem happened probably because I'm based in China. I have checked https://flutter.dev/community/china , and followed their steps. But I'm just not quite sure if everything I did was 100% right since I'm not really familiar with all the coding terminologies yet(
This is just my guessing, probably this isn't the reason why I'm getting this Unhandled exception error.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:508:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:862:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:869:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:890:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Comment: Whats the output of "flutter doctor"?

Comment: just checked. its the same as above.

Comment: Uninstalling Previous APK from device(emulator) did the trick for me , flutter clean didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I think you have use the VPN connection.